# Safe Android Emulator App for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, emulator

I am searching for an Android Emulator Application for Windows which is safe to login to social media and other accounts.

I am not talking about Safe for PC: Whatever information I enter in the applications in emulator, it will be able to see that information. And if I login to my accounts, emulator will also be able to see my passwords.

I am searching for a emulator which doesn't care what we do in the application and doesn't see the data we enter.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe to login to social media"? What has the emulator to do with that? IMHO that much more depends on the *apps* you're using to login. Also, your details given are few; what are your other criteria? What specific features do you need, how much are you willing to pay if it comes to that, and would it be OK if the software requires registration? You can find a small list of available emulators at the end of [this page](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators) (disclosure: that's my site).

Comment: @Izzy Whatever information I enter in the applications in emulator, it will be able to see that information. And if I login to my accounts, emulator will also be able to see my passwords. I am searching for a emulator which don't cares what we do in the application and don't see the data we enter.

Comment: Afraid such doesn't exist then – as it's hard to cover the "doesn't see which data we enter". If it doesn't see that, it can't pass it to the apps. But the idea is clear, and summed up as "a privacy friendly emulator". Good luck with that! Hope you find it.

Comment: Since the emulator fully controls the emulated program, *ALL* input and output it generates must go though it. It's a requirement for it to be able to emulate to also know all data entered and all output generated, there is no way around that. Of course, another thing is that it cares about that.